# Howto someFunction(List<acceptDifferentTypesHere> list) { /*reflection stuff*/ }

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, collections

I want to generate a DataTables out of Lists.

so f.e. I got two lists

```
List<typeA> listA = new List<typeA>(); 
List<typeB> listB = new List<typeB>();
```

how can I get a function accepting both (or more than theese) Lists with different element type?

```
private void someFunction(List<acceptDifferentTypesHere> list)
{ 
   /*elementwise reflection stuff*/
}
```

Any help would be nice,

Harry

Comment: do you know typeA or typeB at compile time ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private void someFunction<T>(List<T> list)
{ 
   /*elementwise reflection stuff*/
}
```

Used as follows

```
someFunction<typeA>(listA);
someFunction<typeB>(listB);
```

Comment: it yells: "Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class"

Comment: You aren't using an extension method or you aren't showing code that is causing the error

Comment: @Harry make sure to select this as the accepted answer then :D

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to do more with your different types (access methods, properties).

```
 private void someFunction<T>(List<T> list) where T : MyType, new()
    { 
       /*elementwise reflection stuff*/

       var instance = new T();
       Type type = instance.GetType();
       instance.MyMethod();    
    } 

    public class MyType
    {        
       public void MyMethod()
       {

       }
    }
```

you can further extend this.. (e.g. use MyType as a generalization of typeA and typeB .. etc.)